# Error: Could not find or load main class xxx

Tags: java, cmd, compiler-errors, command-prompt

So I am trying to compile and run a Java program from cmd prompt. I've had problems with my environment variables and I've been trying many approaches with them. However in the end I run into `"Error: could not find or load main class xxx"` and I don't know what to do. I do believe that it has something to do with my environment variables. Here is how they look.

variables for user:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
CLASSPATH = %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\
path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin
```

system variables:

```
Path : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
classpath : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\lib
```

I am trying to compile and run a Java program using command prompt. The compilation goes smoothly.

I am using javac *.java methods, and then java xxx.

What should I do?

Comment: how are you trying to run it? Is there a main method? .... ?

Comment: I am trying to run it from command prompt. Yes there is a main method. The program works in intellij.

Comment: Please show - in the question - *exactly* how you're trying to run it.

Comment: are you running the code from the correct directory in the prompt?

Comment: Your classpath shouldn't point to the JRE library. That's loaded by default. It should include all the jars - and directories containing class files - that your program needs (which are not part of standard java).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try to change it, and sorry if my question seems a bit vague, I am still learning